# How to use Masonry with "columnWidth" in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, masonry

I am using the [masonry package](https://masonry.desandro.com/) from Desandro. It works fine on Firefox, but on Chrome it doesn't work with the `columnWidth` property. It shows only a one column masonry. Without the property it works, but than the responsive switch from two columns to one column doesn't work.

It should be a two column by default and a one column on small devices. I don't know what is wrong but now it doesn't work on Firefox either.

I am using it on this [webpage](http://holisticnarratives.de).

**jQuery**

```js
let $grid = $(".grid").masonry({
    itemSelector: ".grid-item",
    percentPosition: true,
    columnWidth: ".grid-sizer",
    gutter: 10,
});

// layout Masonry after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $grid.masonry();
});
```

**CSS**

```css
.grid {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
    width: calc((100% - 20px) / 2);
}

.grid-item {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.grid-item-2 {
    width: calc((100% - 20px) / 2);
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .grid-item,
    .grid-item-2 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in the Chrome JS console?

Comment: @ZoliSzabó no errors in the console of Chrome or Firefox :/

Answer (score 0):

(Most probably) it only works correctly when the `.grid-item`s are direct children of the `.grid` container.

In your case there is a `.inner` div in the between, so you could try:

```
$(".grid .inner").masonry(...);
```

PS: it is not working fine right now in Firefox either (at least in my case).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes now it doesn't work on FIrefox either, as I wrote in the text. I don't know what I changed, but first it worked on Firefox like a charm and in Chrome only without "columnWidth". It doesn't change anything if I disable the `.inner` element. If I use `$(".grid .inner").masonry(...);` everything brokes :D On Firefox it works without columnWidth but on Chrome it doesn't work with the responsive Layout